# Is it ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY to use Composer to manage a Drupal 8 project?

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php, drupal-8

Apologies in advance if this is off-topic, or something that has been asked before, but is there a way to maintain a stable Drupal 8 website WITHOUT using Composer?

Why I ask is because I am just unable to use Composer on my shared GoDaddy hosting. While it is powerful enough to run multiple drupal 7 and 8 installations, it seems to come to its knees as soon as I run a composer command using ssh (via terminal). Things freeze for a while and then I get a "Killed" message. If I check server processor, I/O or RAM statistics during this time, they are all in the red.

I have read somewhere else on this site that it is not advisable to run composer on a live site. The recommended approach is to run composer on a local (localhost) copy of the website, and upload updated files, but it seems impractical, because sometimes all I need to do is install a small module, or something else that involves only a few files.

Any insight is very welcome. If I am doing something wrong, please suggest the right path. Things have reached a head now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In a  basic , composer  downloads libs  and  creates autoloader.

So if you have the same/similar(php version !!) enviroment on localhost  and on server  you can simply upload  vendor dir  to  server ( and that's all) .

It'll be  working  till you add some new lib ( then  you need to upload  vendor dir again)

So anwsering -  you don't need ssh and  composer on server.

Comment: Thanks. But what about the modules folder? If I install/update/uninstall a module, wouldn't I need to upload that folder as well? Also, how does one upgrade the Drupal version using Composer? I tried several methods on both localhost and server, and it just wouldn't upgrade the Drupal version...

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use composer at all, it's just a lot easier.
You can just manually add / remove (uninstall first) modules with FTP ... I don't recommend this though!

Comment: Thanks. The problem with manually adding/removing modules using FTP or even the built-in 'Extend' menu in Drupal 8 to install/unistall modules is that the dependencies do not get installed (let's forget about them being uninstalled automatically, for now!), thus throwing up a lot of errors, and in a lot of cases, rendering a website non-working. While I agree that Composer makes things a whole lot easier, if it won't run on standard web servers (talking about a shared GoDaddy Deluxe hosting package here), there should be an alternative, right?